# на день рождения vs на дне рождения

Tags: падежи, предлоги

Beginner here.  There are 2 similiar sentences talking about a birthday, but use a different case and I am confused why.

The first is `Вчера я была у Тамары на дне рождения.`

Translation: `Yesterday, I was at Tamara's for her birthday.`

And the second is `Кого ты пригласил на день рождения?`

Translation: `Whom did you invite for your birthday.`

From what I can gather, the first declinates like

`дне` - locative/prepositional
`рождения` - genitive (day of birth?)

`день` - accusative (guessing its not nominative)
`рождения` - genitive (day of birth?)

So the first question, is the above correct?

The second question is why the difference?  My guess from looking at [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0#Russian)  would be accusative is used to say something was for a particular date (more focus on purpose) and locative is used to say something was on a particular date.

Is that correct?  Could you give a few other examples?

Would it still be correct to say `Кого ты пригласил на дне рождения?` like whom did you invite on your birthday?  If so, how would the connotation of the question change?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you've parsed it correctly.

The *Prepositional/Locative* case describes a stationary condition while the *Accusative* describes movement/directionality.

The difference is of the same kind as in [German](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/german/german-prepositions/) if you happen to know it.

> Positional: Das Buch liegt **auf dem** Tisch. (The book is on the
>   table.)  - Книга лежит **на** сто**лЕ**
>   Directional: Ich lege den Buch **auf den** Tisch. (I place the book on the
>   table.)  - Я кладу книгу **на** сто**л**

Only in German the Dative is the equivalent of Russian Locative for this purpose.

`Кого ты пригласил на дне рождения?` means `Whom did you invite AT your birthday?` that is the invitation was handed *while at* the birthday party.

The difference can be highlighted with the following sentence

> **На** моём **дне** рождения <sup>*Locative*</sup> мой друг пригласил меня **на**
>   свой **день** рождения <sup>*Accusative*</sup>
>
> **At** <sup>*Locative*</sup> my birthday party my
>   friend invited me **to** <sup>*Accusative*</sup> his birthday party

So when you need to decide what case to use you may be guided by questions **Где?** (Where?) and **Куда?** (Whereto/whither?). The first implies a *place/static condition* and so requires *Prepositional/Locative*, the second implies *direction/goal/destination* and therefore requires *Accusative*.

Other examples

> Cидя <sup>*Where?*</sup> **в** комнат**е** <sup>*Locative*</sup>, я смотрю <sup>*Whereto?*</sup> **в** окн**о** <sup>*Accusative*</sup>
>
> Я встал **на** рук**и** <sup>*Accusative*</sup> и стою **на** рук**ах** <sup>*Locative*</sup>

In Russian there're 4 prepositions with varying case governance depending on the type of activity: **на, в, под, за**

**НА / В           ПОД / ЗА**

**`Positional`**                   Prep./Loc.             Instr.

**`Directional`**                             Accusative

Comment: _Only in German the **Genitive** is the equivalent of Russian Locative for this purpose._ Do you mean Dative?

Comment: @Litho my mistake, thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

Consider it as a party, a birthday party. If you are asked "Where were you yesterday?" – At Tamara's party.На дне рождения.(**location, place**).
When you invite people to your party, to visit a place, an event, it's like they will go to your place, movement, приглашаю на день рождения (accusative - день).Compare it with location --**movement/direction** (at school – в школе, to school – в школу).

> Мы были на празднике. Он пригласил нас на праздник.Мы были в театре. Мы ходили в театр. Она пригласила нас в театр.

You can say Кого ты пригласил на дне рождения потанцевать? Who did you invite to dance at the party?

Answer (score 0):

It is дне because день is in the prepositional case (предложный падеж) with на; it indicates the location, where you are.
You cannot say "Кого ты пригласил на дне рождения?" because you want to have на + винителный падеж (accusative): invite TO your birthday.

Answer (score 0):

The word "день" is declinable in this situation - на днЕ рождениЯ
because it's Предложный падеж. The question  for word день is на чём? - на дне
and than the second question is to word "рождение" - на дне ЧЕГО? рождениЯ